# access element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario:

```js
$("a.red").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop action-buttons"> 
    <a class="blue" href="/Company/Details?Id=' + Id + '"> 
        <i class="icon-zoom-in bigger-130"></i> blue
    </a> 
    <a class="green" href="/Company/Edit?Id=' + Id + '"> 
        <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130"></i> green
    </a> 
    <a class="red" id="' + Id + '" href="#"> 
        <i class="icon-trash bigger-130 deleteCompany"></i> red
    </a> 
</div>
```

I want to access a element with class="red".
I've tried this :

```
$("a.red").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

but didn't work.
any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: `didn't work` by this what do you mean?what do you expect what is happening

Comment: I've change your question so it includes a code snippet. Works find in that with the code your provided. What jquery version are you using?

Comment: Snippet worked for me

Comment: it works with your code.

Comment: You code should indeed work. Did you include jQuery? On a side note: do you need a jQuery object? `document.querySelector("a.red")` would be an alternative

Comment: yes I have included jquery file , i'm using jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: Have you added click  handler within .ready() function? For me it is working if I put click handler within .ready like this  $(document).ready(function(){
$("a.red").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
});

Answer (score 1):

**Must Include jquery library first.**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this one to access element without click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var content = $(".red").html(); // it will alert the html inside the red class
alert(content);
});
</script>
```

If you want to access through click then, use this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".red").click(function(){
 var content = $(".red").html();
alert(content);
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: what if there are element with class red that is not an anchor?

Comment: To identify/access a particular html element content, there must be an unique item... Either class/id selector

Comment: `<span class='red'>1</span><a class='red'>1</a>` what will happened?

Comment: it will return you the data of the first occurrence for that class

Comment: @SimerjitParmar No $(".red") in above case  will return array of consisting of both span elements. and on both the elements click handler will be applied

Comment: In the fiddle if you add    alert($(".red").length); it will print 2 because it is returning 2 elements. But .html() will consider the first elemets html

Comment: $(".red").click()  will apply click() handler on all matching elements

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6xk6jbc/4/) click on A1 and A2 links and see the result

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery:

```
$(".red").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mvzux2g7/1/

Comment: what if there are element with class red that is not an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have placed click handler inside ready() function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.red").click(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
        });

    });
```

Here is the fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/dmvky0kr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add values between `a` tags!

> https://jsfiddle.net/w8jkr04u/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".red").click(function(){
 var content = $(".red").html();
alert(content);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop action-buttons"> 
    <a class="blue" href="/Company/Details?Id=' + Id + '"> 
        <i class="icon-zoom-in bigger-130">blue</i> 
    </a> 
    <a class="green" href="/Company/Edit?Id=' + Id + '"> 
        <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130">green</i> 
    </a> 
    <a class="red" id="' + Id + '" href="#"> 
        <i class="icon-trash bigger-130 deleteCompany">Red</i> 
    </a> 
</div>
```